# grafana postgres data source test returns "Metric request error"

Tags: postgresql, docker, grafana, prometheus, timescaledb

I have deployed a docker container using the TimescaleDB extension to Postgres as a persistent store for metrics collected by Prometheus.  This includes deploying the Prometheus Postgres adapter in a separate container.  And then I deployed grafana in a third container.

Inside the TimescaleDB container I can execute the query:

```
SELECT time_bucket('5 minutes', time) AS five_min_bucket, name, avg(value)
FROM metrics
WHERE (name='node_load5' OR name='node_memory_Active_bytes') AND
      time > NOW() - interval '1 day'
GROUP BY five_min_bucket,name
ORDER BY five_min_bucket;
```

and it returns these rows from the `metrics` table:

```
   five_min_bucket     |           name           |        avg
------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------
 2019-07-13 16:15:00+00 | node_load5               |  1.84263157894737
 2019-07-13 16:15:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |  1055776552.42105
 2019-07-13 16:20:00+00 | node_load5               |  1.62533333333333
 2019-07-13 16:20:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |      1070225817.6
 2019-07-13 16:25:00+00 | node_load5               |  1.06166666666667
 2019-07-13 16:25:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |  1084650018.13333
 2019-07-13 16:30:00+00 | node_load5               | 0.593333333333333
 2019-07-13 16:30:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |  1093145668.26667
 2019-07-13 16:35:00+00 | node_load5               | 0.322333333333333
 2019-07-13 16:35:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |  1108816145.06667
 2019-07-13 16:40:00+00 | node_load5               | 0.180666666666667
 2019-07-13 16:40:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |      1125213388.8
 2019-07-13 16:45:00+00 | node_load5               |             0.126
 2019-07-13 16:45:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |  1134488098.13333
 2019-07-13 16:50:00+00 | node_load5               | 0.133333333333333
 2019-07-13 16:50:00+00 | node_memory_Active_bytes |        1162440704
(16 rows)
```

The grafana container is run as:

```
docker run \
-d \
-p 3000:3000 \
--name=grafana \
-v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana \
-e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-kubernetes-app" \
 grafana/grafana
```

When I launch a browser to `http://104.XX.XX.XX:3000` I can log into the web-ui and define the Datasource to postgres, but I received the error 'Metric request error'.

I looked for the grafana logs in its container and the path `/var/log/grafana` is empty.  This is the log location indicated when I do a `docker inspect` command.

Using Chrome, I am able to inspect the Console and it reports the server responded with an internal error of 500.

[image]

On the host, I can confirm the docker-proxy is listening on port 5432.

```
sudo netstat -antp | grep "5432"
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:49486        172.17.0.2:5432         ESTABLISHED 60631/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      60631/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.4:5432           172.18.0.2:38568        ESTABLISHED 60631/docker-proxy
```

How do I get grafana to fetch metrics stored in the postgres database?

Comment: Ok, it looks like I forget to include the ```--network prometheus_timescale_network``` argument, which uses the bridge driver when building the containers, and am going to re-deploy.

Comment: After deploying with all containers deployed with ```--network prometheus_timescale_network``` I still get the error ```{data: {…}, status: 500, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "Internal Server Error", …}
config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), paramSerializer: ƒ, jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", …}
data: {message: "Metric request error"}
headers: ƒ (n)
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object

Comment: ```{data: {…}, status: 500, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "Internal Server Error", …}
config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), paramSerializer: ƒ, jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", …}
data: {message: "Metric request error"}
headers: ƒ (n)
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
xhrStatus: "complete"
__proto__: Object```